# How can I tell which account contacts have synced from?

Tags: contacts, sync

I've just noticed that I've suddenly had 7 contacts appear in my list all called "Me Mob" all with my mobile's phone number as the only entry. I don't know when they appeared, but I don't think they've been there for long.

When I open these contacts up, I can see a Joined Contacts section with a generic icon and no details, clicking that just says "Unknown" "Me Mob".
[image: Unknown contacts in list]

Is there any way that I can tell where all of these have come from?

Galaxy S, running stock Samsung 2.2.1 OS in case it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **Contacts** app, under `Menu | Display options` I can select which of my accounts contacts' to display (and, in the case of Gmail contacts, which groups to display). Assuming Samsung hasn't monkeyed with that, you should be able to determine which account they're from by process of elimination.

Comment: Thanks, the process of elimination approach should have occurred to me! They seem to have arrived from Skype's contacts sync, quite why there's 7 of them I don't know but at least I know who's help and support to look through! Can't help feeling there should be a better way to identify where a contact comes from that that though, who knows how many accounts we'll be syncing in the future.